# What is the number of tiles needed to cover a rectangular floor given diagram?

Tags: geometry, word-problem, rectangles

A square tile measures 6 inches by 6 inches. What is the least number of tiles needed to cover a rectangular floor area of 9 feet by 12 feet?

[image]

So the first thing i tried to do was divide 9 by 6 and then 12/6 and then multiply them together. That gave me 3 which wasn't the right answer. how do you solve this?

Comment: 12 inch? do i translate inches into feet?

Comment: So the tiles shouldn't exactly cover the rectangular? How would i do this?

Comment: I am living in a metric world and expected some funny non-integer multiple, set by some body property of an ancient ruler. But it is just boring $1:12$. (More funny is that my shoe size seems to be one foot, hah)

Answer (score 2):

As there seem to be 12 inches per foot, you can easily cover a square of side length one foot with four tiles. As the given rectangle can readily be partitioned into $9\cdot 12=108$ such squares, you need $4\cdot 108=432$ tiles.

Comment: could i have also divided the the Length after turning it into inches, like 12ft=144 inches. and then i divided 144/6 and then did the same with the other one and multiplied in the end.would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Two tiles will have a side length of one foot. So we need 18 in vertical and 24 in horizonstal direction, which makes $18\cdot 24 = 432$ tiles.